# AngularJS: AJAX return is a String and not an Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, node.js

I have a node.js server. This server has a small API. I build an App with AngularJS and my problem is that if I make an ajax-call to the server i get a string back and not an object.

Server API:

```
exports.api = function(req, res, next) {

  var path = req.body.path
  var method = req.body.method

  digest.request({
    host: 'xxx',
    path: path,
    port: 80,
    method: method,
    headers: { "User-Agent": "Bridge" }
  }, function (resX) {
    resX.on('data', function (data) {
      res.status(200).end(data)
    })
    resX.on('error', function (err) {
      res.status(200).end(err)
    })
  })
}
```

Call:

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/api'}
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
  })
})
```

I hope someone can help me because I despair.

Comment: could you show the string returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding content type to the request according to your data (to let the function know what to expect back).

Additionally you could try using JSON utilities to convert the data to an object. E.g.:

http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-convert-JSON-format-string-into-a-real-object-in-JS

Depends on what you are actually getting back.

Comment: I added a content type to the call and JSON.parse but now I get an error: Error: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 [...]

Comment: Hmmm. Could you show the exact string returned? Preferably - through breakpoint and watch, but whatever is more convenient.
If you can setup a jsfiddle - that would be even better :)

Comment: I can't setup jsfiddle because the node js server runs only local :/ 

Here is the console.log: 
https://gist.github.com/mateuszbrylski/06f83d8689e332a46551

It is even more but the browser shows only this.